# Validate PHP GET form to an array?

Tags: php, validation

I am writing a code that I am sure is very simple, but for some reason I am having trouble. It seems like it would be logical to write it out as it is. If the $_GET != $arr then return false with an error.

The situation is we give two different groups a code, there are three codes in all. The third code is a catch all that takes them to a form that is un-modified, so it is an initial value or will be. The other two take them to two different forms that is assigned to each code.

What I am trying to get to do is if they enter the code correct then fine it redirects them, if they do not enter anything they get an error that says sorry you must enter your code. If they enter it wrong an error that says check your code and try again or call this number for help.

The error is where I am having trouble creating. If you would help me figure out how to validate the $_GET form to the arrays and if it comes out false to pop out the error.

```
   <?php

$arr = array(001,002,003);
    if ($_GET['code'] === "001") {
        header("Location: http://stackoverflow.com/");      
    }
    if ($_GET['code'] === "002") {
        header("Location: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/");
    }
    if ($_GET['code'] === "003") {
        header("Location: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/");
    }
if ($_GET ['code'] != $arr); 
else {
echo("Uh oh, you did not enter the correct code error message");
}
?>
</head>

<body>
<form id="galaonly" name="galaonly" method="get" action="">
  <input name="code" type="text" value="001" size="50" maxlength="150" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['code'])){
    $arr = array('001', '002', '003');

    if(in_array($_GET['code'], $arr, true)){
        if($_GET['code'] === '001'){
            header("Location: http://stackoverflow.com/");
        } elseif($_GET['code'] === '002') {
            header("Location: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/");
        } elseif($_GET['code'] === '003'){
            header("Location: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/");
        }
    } else{
        echo 'Uh oh, you did not enter the correct code error message';
    }   
}
?>

</head>

<body>
<form id="galaonly" name="galaonly" method="get" action="">
  <input name="code" type="text" value="001" size="50" maxlength="150" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: The echo always shows on the page. That was a problem I had before, I thought I was doing something wrong. It acts as if it is not waiting for an event. Looks just like copy on the page.

Comment: Ahh this one worked perfectly! Thank you. I hope I was not too far off from just learning.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (!in_array($_GET['code'], $arr)) {
```

to catch an invalid code.

However, I think that this section of code would be better written using a `switch` statement, provided that the codes won't change too often.

Answer (score 1):

i think you mean the following:

```
if (! in_array($_GET ['code'], $arr))
    echo('error');
```

but you could also do it like so:

```
$arr = array(
    '001' => 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
    '002' => 'http://gaming.stackexchange.com/',
    '003' => 'http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/'
);

if (isset($_GET['code']) {
    if (isset($arr[$_GET['code']])
        header("Location: " . $arr[$_GET['code']);
    else
        echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: The page just says error the whole time, no submit action needed as if it is part of the copy on the page.

Comment: and make the array values strings

Comment: right...the array **keys** have to be strings. edited my answer, try my second approach!

Comment: I am looking to why it is giving me a syntax error on the header line.

Comment: this is because you didn't check if the formular is sent. I edited my answer: added `if (isset($_GET['code'])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use switch construction

```
switch $_GET['code']
{
case "001":
    // your code
  break;
  case "002":
    // your code
  break;
  case "003":
    // your code
  break;
  default:
    echo("Uh oh, you did not enter the correct code error message");
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
$pages = array(
    '001' => 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
    '002' => 'http://gaming.stackexchange.com/',
    '003' => 'http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/'
);
$code = $_GET['code'];
if (in_array($code, $pages, true)) { // The true here makes in_array check for type as well.
    header("Location: " . $pages[$code]);
} else {
    echo("Uh oh, you did not enter the correct code error message");
}
```

I think you were just looking for [the in_array() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

EDIT:
The advantage of this approach (as opposed to using a switch or if/else construct) is that it's quicker and easier to maintain, and properly expresses the idea that you're mapping codes to redirect URLs. If you end up with a lot of these codes, you can load the array from a CSV file or something like that, meaning that you won't even have to edit your source code.

Comment: I am unable to get the echo to stay off the page until a user clicks. The echo just stays on the page.

Comment: is $_GET['code'] always set? If it isn't, you'll want to wrap my if in an `if isset($_GET['code']))` and do something else if the value hasn't been set.

Comment: It is always at the http://webaddress.edu/page.php with an initial value on the input. So if the URL is empty on a get will it assume it as an error?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function. Like this:

```
<?php 

if (!in_array($_GET['code'], $arr)) {
    echo("Uh oh, you did not enter the correct code error message");
}
```

You can also use the php [switch/case](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement instead of the multiple if statements. In which case you don't need the error check separately, you can use switch/case's default to catch the error.
Like this -

```
<?php 

switch($_GET['code']) {
    case '001':
        header("http://location1");
        break;
    case '002':
        header("http://location2");
        break;
    case '003': 
        header("http://location3");
        break;
    default:
        echo("Uh oh, you did not enter the correct code error message");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you want

```
if ($_GET['code'] == "001") {
        header("Location: http://stackoverflow.com/");      
    }
    else if ($_GET['code'] == "002") {
        header("Location: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/");
    }
    else if ($_GET['code'] == "003") {
        header("Location: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/");
    }
    else {
       echo "Uh oh, you did not enter the correct code error message";
    }
```

Otherwise you're looking for `in_array`

```
if (!in_array($_GET['code'], $arr))
    // error stuff here
```